# Are there any demo sites that let you test IronRuby with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, ironruby

I want to some very basic IronRuby tests, such as checking the syntax on a regular expression, and if possible would like to be able to do it thorugh my browser. Does anyone know of a site that hosts an IronRuby in Silverlight demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Have you found/already tried this?

http://silverlight.net/samples/sl2/dlrconsole/index.html

Note, this is an older build, so you might wish to follow my 2nd suggestion if you want something a bit fresher:

2) If you have built IronRuby recently from the latest source from [GitHub](http://github.com/ironruby/ironruby/tree/master)
You should find a Tutorial (which runs in WPF or Silverlight) .

You'd find it [here in the source tree](http://github.com/ironruby/ironruby/tree/e485f39001bf646bcefc8a54fa2834c7de2bf03b/Merlin/Main/Languages/Ruby/Samples/Tutorial)

**Edit:** Also, I know Jimmy has posted recently about some additional work going into this tutorial, so I believe this is being actively worked on.

**Edit 2:**

3) Perhaps will or will not suffice for your needs, but there is also [Gestalt](http://visitmix.com/labs/gestalt/) for running IronRuby/IronPython in the browser. This is a recent interesting development from mix online labs.

Comment: That's the site I was after, thanks. I had come across it in the past but couldn't find it. The best I found was http://jimmy.schementi.com/silverlight/repl/ which looks like it's using a pretty old IronRuby version.

Comment: Great! If possible, I'd suggest keeping tabs on the Tutorial mentioned above too, since it seems likely to be receiving significant updates over time (In fact, it looks like Jimmy committed some updates for it just yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

John Lam, the original iron Ruby guy, has a tutorial for doing just what you ask at:
http://www.iunknown.com/2008/03/dynamic-silverl.html

Comment: I was hoping to find a site running the demo he mentions though. I could download it and host it myself somewhere but that's a disproportionate amount of effort for the use I want to give it.